# Python subtraction with large numbers

Tags: python

I was playing around with large numbers in Python and I ran the calculation of

```
2**(1322134)
```

and it obviously took a long time to calculate. However when I ran the calculation of

```
2**(1322134) - 2**(1322134)
```

it instantly returned 0.

How does Python automatically tell these are the same numbers without doing the calculations?

Comment: Did you run this from a Python interactive shell?

Comment: 2^(1322134) took no time to calculate, what are you talking about?

Comment: Never mind ... I tried it myself to validate.

Comment: `^` is the xor operator. Did you mean `**` (power)?

Answer (score 5):

The slow part is printing the number, not computing it:

```
In [1]: %timeit str(2**1322134)
1 loop, best of 3: 2.28 s per loop

In [2]: %timeit 2**1322134
10000000 loops, best of 3: 24.8 ns per loop
```

You can see this by storing the results in variables:

```
>>> x = 2**1322134
>>> y = 2**1322134
>>> x - y
0
```

The above code will execute instantly because Python won't have to print out almost 400,000 digits to your screen.

Comment: Never though about that :) Note that printing to `stdout` also includes additional overhead. (398002 characters!)

Answer (score 3):

Actually I can't reproduce the example:

```
i = 1322134
%timeit 2 ** i - 2 ** i  # 10 loops, best of 3: 24.8 ms per loop
```

takes (roughly) twice the time that

```
i = 1322134
%timeit 2 ** i  # 100 loops, best of 3: 12.7 ms per loop
```

takes.

There is one exception - if you "hardcode" your value:

```
%timeit 2 ** 1322134  # 10000000 loops, best of 3: 61.5 ns per loop
%timeit 2 ** 1322134 - 2 ** 1322134  # 10000000 loops, best of 3: 61.3 ns per loop
```

because Python then calculates this "constant" when it translates it to bytecode and only looks it up at runtime (pretty much for free).

---

You can always check the Python operations by checking it with `dis.dis`:

```
import dis

def func1():
    return 2 ** 1322134 - 2 ** 1322134

dis.dis(func1)
#  2           0 LOAD_CONST               5 (0)  # just loads the constant
#              3 RETURN_VALUE

def func2():
    i = 1322134
    return 2 ** i - 2 ** i

dis.dis(func2)
#  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (1322134)
#              3 STORE_FAST               0 (i)
#
#  3           6 LOAD_CONST               2 (2)
#              9 LOAD_FAST                0 (i)
#             12 BINARY_POWER
#             13 LOAD_CONST               2 (2)
#             16 LOAD_FAST                0 (i)
#             19 BINARY_POWER
#             20 BINARY_SUBTRACT
#             21 RETURN_VALUE
```

So the `func2` does all specified operations it should do, while `func1` just loads and returns the already pre-calculated (calculation was done at translation time!) value.

---

And if you're wondering why it takes so long to display it I think [`@Blender`s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41993419/5393381) is correct. If you want to display something then Python prints the `repr(obj)` to `sys.stdout` - so you have one case where 1 character (`0`) is converted to a string and then printed and the other case where 398,002 characters need to be created, passed around and printed. Just creating the `repr` is pretty slow:

```
i = 1322134
%timeit repr(2 ** i - 2 ** i)  # 10 loops, best of 3: 24.7 ms per loop
%timeit repr(2 ** i)           # 1 loop, best of 3: 6.34 s per loop  # <--- whoops that's slow!
```

Comment: I have no trouble producing the effect on my command line:  2 \*\* i - 2 \*\* i returns **0L** immediately.  However, I do get the same disassembly you show when it's encapsulated in a function.  I don't have the %timeit directive to check that performance.

Answer (score 1):

**CAVEAT:  The initial explanation below is wrong.  I leave it here as an example of self-education and community work.**  I achieved it with my education in advanced compiler construction and *partial* knowledge of Python internals.

----  WRONG ANSWER  ----

The expression handler has optimizations built in.  The expression evaluator for the subtraction would work something like this:

```
 1. reserve space for first operand:
    2 already exists as a frequently-used small integer
    temp1 = 1322134
    temp2 = 2^(temp1)
 2. reserve space for second operand:
    2 already exists
    13322134 already exists as temp1
    2^(temp1) already exists as temp2
 3. reserve space for the result:
    temp3 = temp2 - temp2
Hey!  That's a really easy operation!
    The result is 0, which already exists as a frequently-used small integer.
```

----  END OF WRONG ANSWER  ----

MORE EXPERIMENTS

To test the operations, I made these adjustments:

1. Don't print the result; this eliminates text conversion time.
2. Loop many times to accumulate actual computation time.
3. Change the exponent to reduce the possibility of a result being cached from the previous iteration.

Code:

```
>>> def pow2(i):
...   for _ in range(1000):
...      qqq = 2 ** i
...      i += 1
... 
>>> def powsub(i):
...   for _ in range(1000):
...      qqq = 2 ** i - 2 ** i
...      i += 1
... 
>>> import time
j = 987654
>>> start = time.time(); pow2(j); print time.time() - start
7.41031980515
>>> start = time.time(); powsub(j); print time.time() - start
15.060614109
```

I also tested the raw looping time, replacing the **qqq** computation with a RHS of **2**.  That took far less than a millisecond.

From this, I observe that

1. The computation time is significant with respect to the control time: the interpreter appears to be carrying out computations in each loop.
2. The subtraction routine takes about twice as long, suggesting that the interpreter is, indeed, doing both computations.
3. The execution time per loop is far less than the time to perform *and print* one computation.

**CONCLUSION**

My original answer is *wrong*.
MSeifert and Blender nailed it.

I'm leaving this answer here as a failed counter-example.

Comment: I don't think Python does that. It includes some optimizations (see my answer) - but as far as I know it doesn't actually does code optimizations by rearranging like you describe.

Comment: First, see my comment to your answer.  This is getting interesting.  Perhaps the optimization isn't perfectly accurate, but the interpreter is doing *something*.  To test, I tried a variety of things from the Python command line (straight Python 2.7 -- no Jupyter or other wrapper).  I still got a function being slow, while the command line subtraction is immediate.

Comment: I now also believe that the bottlenech is `repr(....)` and printing it to `stdout`. The calculation takes a few ms (is not immediate) but definetly barely noticable.

Comment: I finally reduced it.  I started a new Python interactive session, fed it i=345678 (a value I hadn't used before, after using 234567 to show a noticeable time lag).  Then I gave it 2 \*\* i - 2 \*\* i, and again received 0L immediately.  From previous experiments, I'd expect at least a 2-second lag to compute the value once.  *Now I'm really curious!*

Comment: Ah ... good thought on the __repr__!  I'm going to go time a few things ...

Comment: Almost; I also worried about an optimization lifting the invariant result (for the exponentiation) out of the loop.

Comment: Do you have a source for "The expression handler has optimizations built in"? (Great answer, by the way, even though you got the wrong result. It clearly demonstrates *an approach* – including the consideration it might not be the right one.)

Comment: @RadLexus ... yes, I have a source -- which turns out to be an error on my part.  I combined a phrase from my education with a phrase from my Python learning/teaching, and came up with an invalid inference.  That's what led me so neatly to the wrong answer.  Thanks for the compliment; that's why I'm leaving the answer here.  *I* learned enough from this mistake that I'm hoping it will help others.